# Help with SQL syntax

Tags: sql, oracle, ibatis

I am not very good with sqls and I am trying to understand an sql statement which I haven't seen before. We're using Oracle and the IBatis framework so this might be specific to one of those. I am not really sure.

```
SELECT 
....
,....
,....
, PKG_LABEL.GET_LABEL_NAME('UOM',T100.CASE_DIM_UOM_CODE) AS caseDimensionsUOM
, PKG_LABEL.GET_LABEL_NAME('UOM',T100.ITEM_DIM_UOM_CODE) AS itemDimensionsUOM
, PKG_LABEL.GET_LABEL_NAME('UOM',T100.CASE_WEIGHT_UOM_CODE) AS caseWeightUOM
, PKG_LABEL.GET_LABEL_NAME('UOM',T100.PALLET_WEIGHT_UOM_CODE) AS unitNetWeightUOM

FROM 

[..snipped..]
```

At first glance I thought the PKG_LABEL was merely a table alias but it seems that it is calling a function. I haven't had much experience with stored procedures so I am wondering if it is one.

I would have looked this up in Google but I don't know what it exactly is so I don't know what search term to use.

A brief explanation and some links will be okay.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't know much about iBatis, but PKG_LABEL here could be a 'package' in the database.
To see if a package with that name exists, you can run this query

```
SELECT * FROM user_objects
    WHERE    object_type = 'PACKAGE' AND object_name = 'PKG_LABEL';
```

You can get to know about packages [here](http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/B28359_01/appdev.111/b28370/packages.htm#CIHIJECJ)

Comment: I chose your answer because you gave me a way to verify if the package exists. Thanks :)

Comment: Are packages an Oracle feature or is it a standard for relational databases?

Comment: Packages are specific to Oracle and are a convenient way of grouping together related stored procedures and functions.

Comment: You said that it COULD be a 'package' in a database. If it's not package then what could it be?

Comment: @Jeune - As I said, i have no idea about iBATIS, so thought it 'could' be something related to it..if it is not a PACKAGE.

Comment: @Jeune, only SELECT object_type FROM user_objects WHERE object_name = 'PKG_LABEL'; will tell you

Answer (score 2):

PKG_LABEL probably refers to a package.

Thats the oracle name for a group of (related) functions/procedures.

Answer (score 2):

Look in your schema a try to find a package names PKG_LABEL.

In its body, you should find a function named GET_LABEL_NAME , take a look at its code to know what it does...

Answer (score 2):

PKG_LABEL is a PL/SQL [package](http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14220/sqlplsql.htm#sthref3652), which is a collection of PL/SQL [functions and procedures](http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14220/sqlplsql.htm#sthref3608).  GET_LABEL_NAME is a function within that package, which will perform some logic on its arguments and return a value (probably a character string in this case).